# is there a major difference between using a range of range (i[0], len(i) and

Tags: python, range

I am brand new to python. I have been learning this on my own. I always make sure to exhaust every resource before asking a question on here.

but I will show you two sets of code. One does what I want, the other doesn't the only difference that appears to me, is how the ranges are set up. I don't understand the significance of this difference. Could someone please explain?

Thank you.

**Code that works**

```
def geometric(lst):
    'checks whether the integers in list lst form a geometric sequence'
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return True

    ratio = lst[1]/lst[0]
    for i in range(1, len(lst)-1):
        if lst[i+1]/lst[i] != ratio:
            return False
    return True
```

**code that doesn't **

```
def geometric(integerList):
    'checks whether the integers in list lst form a geometric sequence'
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return True

    ratio = integerList[1]/integerList[0]
    for i in range (integerList[0], len(integerList))
        if lst[i+1]/lst[i] != ratio:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: use `enumerate` and what is `integerList`?

Comment: The first code block iterates over the whole list(`range(1, len(lst)-1)`) where as the second code block iterates over the list from whatever the value of the first item is to the last item(`range (integerList[0], len(integerList))`).

Comment: integerList is just an input place holder for the function i defined

Comment: In both examples, the indexing is at fault. The range should be 0 to length-2, because your loop variable `i` is indexing at `i+1`.

Comment: `lst` doesn't exist in the second function. Is that a typo, or the root of your problem?

Comment: @Noelkd if I may, if thats the case why wouldn't it be lst(range(0,len(lst)-1)? as it is in strings? Or is it only in strings that 0 refers to the first item in it?

Comment: @chepner sorry, thats a typo

Comment: @ChristopherJakob, you explicitly start from the second element by starting your range at 1

Comment: @ChristopherJakob I think in the first one they start from the second item because you have used the first item in making the ratio.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `range(1, len(lst)-1)` is a list

```
1, 2, 3, ..., len(lst)-1
```

In the second case, it depends on the value of the first list element. If `integerList[0]` is 3, then `range()` is

```
3, 4, 5,  ..., len(lst)-1
```

and the first call of the `if()` statement compares `integerList[4] / integerList[3]` and ignores the first three elements in the list. So, the code only works, if `integerList[0] == 1`

However, there are two further pitfalls:

1. range() only takes integers as elements. If the first element is a float, pyhon will throw an error.
2. If the ratio always is an integer, you can compare the ratios for equality, as you do. **But** if ratio is a floating value, you can get into trouble: Though two ratios are mathematically equal, a computer (due to its floating point arithmetic) may calculate *slightly* different values. It is better to use

   `import math
   ...
   if (math.fabs(lst[i+1]/lst[i] - ratio) < smallNumber)`

where `smallNumer` is a very small number suitable for you.

By the way: In your second code, you use `lst[]` , but I guess, it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

As Noelkd said, the `range` in your second code block starts with the **value** of the first element of the list, not its **position**.

If my list is the geometric sequence `(1, 2, 4, 8, 16)`, your first block's range is

```
range(1, len(lst)-1) =
range(1, 5 - 1) =
range(1, 4) =
[1, 2, 3]
```

and your second block's range is

```
range(integerList[0], len(integerList)) =
range(1, 5) =
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This difference gets even weirder if my sequence doesn't start with 1, such as for the sequence `(3, 9, 27)`:

First block's range is

```
range(1, len(lst)-1) =
range(1, 3 - 1) =
range(1, 2) =
[1]
```

and second block's range is

```
range(integerList[0], len(integerList)) =
range(3, 3) =
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless  `integerList[0]` is always equal to `1` then you will not get the same range as `range(1, len(lst)-1)` which starts at 1, if `integerList[0] == 5` your range will be `range(5, len(integerList))` so you would miss elements from indexes  `1 - 4` that you get in your first block of code and it would also throw an index error as `lst[i+1]` would be 1 index past the end of the list:

It would also be better to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def geometric(lst):
    'checks whether the integers in list lst form a geometric sequence'
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return True

    ratio = lst[1] / lst[0]
    for ind, ele in enumerate(lst[1:-1]):
        if lst[ind+1] / ele != ratio:
            return False
    return True


In [4]: lst = ["foo","bar","foobar"]

In [5]: for ind, ele in enumerate(lst):
   ...:     print ind,ele
   ...:     
0 foo
1 bar
2 foobar
```

Comment: thank you @Padraic, unfortunitly for me I have yet to learn enumerate. However  I will look into its usage.

Comment: @ChristopherJakob, ind is the index, ele is the each element. I added an example of how enumerate works

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)-1):
    ...
```

This code first creates a list containing the numbers `[1,2,3,...,len(lst)-1]` and then loops over these values by setting `i` to a value in this list on every iteration.

```
for i in range (integerList[0], len(integerList))
```

This code actually creates a list containing the numbers:

`[integerList[0],integerList[0] + 1,integerList[0] + 2,...,len(integerList)]`

Here you're starting the range at `integerList[0]` not it's index. And if `integerList[0]` is bigger than `len(integerList)` you'll get an array with no values `[]`

You also then try to use `lst` in the second function when really you're looking for `integerList`

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand what's happening:

```
>>> x = [2,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> for i in range(1,len(x)):
...     print x[i]
... 
4
5
6
7
8
```

So that's printing from the second to the last item.

```
>>> for i in range(x[0],len(x)):
...     print x[i]
... 
5
6
7
8
```

The second block is starting from `x[0]` which is 2 so from the third element to the last element.